# Why developing Android today needs to sync with gradle?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

During my college days, I used to code android by using eclipse and `SDK/ADK`.
And now I'm back to programming, I was a bit late about the fast major updates on today's android development. It says that it need to sync with `gradle`. But why?

Comment: because of `fast major updates on today's android development`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer -

- In Android Studio project contains a
  build.gradle(Project:AppName) and a build.gradle(Module:app) file.
  The first contains configuration for all projects and modules in the
  application. The second contains specific configuration for the
  module it’s included with.
- Syncing Gradle will evaluate the build files by comparing the current
  files to the project state that Gradle and Android Studio maintain.
  If it finds any changes it will execute just those specific tasks